# ASP.NET Identity without username and without email

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I am using Azure Table Storage with ASP.NET Identity.

User can login only with social accounts. No email, username nor password.

ASP.NET Identity forces me to have a username.

What shell I do?

As a workaround I dropped ASP.NET Identity and currently I am suing custom service called AccountService to accomplish that.

I posted this question in [CodePlex](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/discussions/587920) as well.

Comment: a quick hack would be  `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "", Email = "" };` on the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method

Comment: I do not have an email neither